# selectOption Required only when Rendered

Tags: visualforce, required-field, rendered, selectoption, selectradio

I have a vf page with radiobuttons. This is rendered only when a condition satisfied.  The radiobuttons need to be mandatory only when it is rendered.  But the problem is even if the radio options are not visible, it gives the error - that radio option must be selected. Here is the code

```
<apex:outputPanel id="packageDelivery" rendered="{!IF(applicantInfo.Category__c=='Student (F)',True,False)}">                               
 <div class="form-row">
 <div class="form-label top"><strong>How should we send Package?<span class="required">*</span></strong></div>
 <div class="form-field">
      <apex:selectRadio id="Package_Delivery" value="{!selectedPackageDelivery}" required="true">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listPackageDelivery}" />
      </apex:selectRadio>
 </div>    
 </div>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

I tried to change the `required="true"` to `required="{!IF(applicantInfo.Category__c=='Student (F)',True,False)}"` but it throws error which I cannot capture.

please help. how to make a field required only when it is rendered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose an alternate way of making it required through apex code validations on Save, instead of checking it at the visualforce component.

Answer (score 0):

VisualForce:

`<apex:form >
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" immediate="false"  />
    <apex:inputField value="{!dummy.Category__c}" required="true" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="packageDelivery" rendered="{!IF(dummy.Category__c=='Student (F)',True,False)}">
    <apex:selectRadio id="Package_Delivery" value="{!selOpt}" required="{!dummy.Category__c=='Student (F)'}">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!listPackageDelivery}" />
      </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form>`

'Category__c' is just a regular text field on my custom object.
My radio buttons are only considered required if Category__c is set to 'Student (F)'

Comment: Nope. it doesn't work too.

Comment: I chose an alternate way of making it required through apex code validations on Save, instead of checking it at the visualforce component.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce your situation and it works fine. I modified my answer to show my entire code...